# How do unnatural processes compare to natural geological processes in the formation of rocks & minerals?

Tags: geology, astronomy

As in an asteroid hitting a planet to make glass & other formations. Are these considered minerals? Can a crystal structure be formed?

Comment: This question suggests no research done. ie search terms "geology mineral definition"  Answer, yes, yes. As the question currently is wored this is not world building.

Comment: Try your question here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=asteroid

Comment: @GaultDrakkor smashing rocks together is precisely how one would build a world ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Being struck by space rocks *is* a natural process for other space rocks, such as the Earth.

There are plenty of real-world materials that have impact origins, such as [tektites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tektite) (which are glasses rather than crystals... there's plenty of further reading out there on [lechatelierites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lechatelierite), which include impact-produced glasses), [shocked quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocked_quartz) (modification of existing crystalline structures). [Widmanstätten patterning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widmanst%C3%A4tten_pattern) is a famous feature of metallic meteors, involving metal crystals:

[image: a photograph of a cross-section of the toluca meteorite, showing characteristic Widmanstätten patterns].

though this sort of thing wouldn't form during an impact, but impacts could potentially deliver large amounts of it and the resulting mixtures are technically novel formations.

Actual large crystal formations such as those you might find on Earth are unlikely, because they often require inconvenient geological conditions to form (often involving large quantities of liquid water which is awkward to find in space, and slow precipitation or growth, which is hard to come by in a meteorite impact). There's a chance you might find oddities like [Moissanites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moissanite) if you were lucky.

Obviously over geological timescales after an impact, hydrological processes will modify impact structures and minerals which might give rise to crystalline minerals growing over sufficient time. This may or may not count, depending on what you actually wanted.

---

*ETA*:

Today I learned of the existence of *[mineraloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineraloid)*. Quoth wikipedia:

> A mineraloid is a naturally occurring mineral-like substance that does not demonstrate crystallinity.[snip] For example, obsidian is an amorphous glass and not a crystal

Tektites would, therefore, presumably be mineraloids, not minerals. Meteors themselves can be [made of minerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_meteorite_minerals) though, and non-glassy materials that are produced in an impact will be minerals too. So there you go!

Comment: Tektites & glass vs minerals & crystals was super helpful, but when is it appropriate to use in worldbuilding? Would it be more convenient to have it happen before my creatures start to develop societies?